# $f: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable non-constant funtion such that $f(0) = f(1)$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem

$f: [0,1] \rightarrow \Bbb R$ be a differentiable non-constant funtion such that $f(0) = f(1)$. Show $\exists$ a point $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f'(x)$ is rational.

Here's what I've done:

I believe that this fact holds true as a consequence of the Mean Value Theroem and Rolle's Theorem.

As f is differentiable $\implies$ f is continuous over this compact set. This means that f attains a max and a min. Now if either maximum or minimum occurs at a point c in the interior $[a, b]$, then $f'(c)=0$ (by the interior extremum theroem) which is rational.

If I could have some guidance whether I'm on the right track that would be great.

Comment: It is such a weird exercise. The assumption $f$ non-constant is unnecessary, since then it is obvious. Otherwise, Rolle gives directly $c \in (0,1)$ such that $f'(c) = 0$.

Comment: It looks like an exercise statement, not a theorem. So I do not see the problem of mentionning unnecessary hypothesis to avoid trivial and non-interesting cases. @Raoul

Comment: @nicomezi If the point is to use Rolle, there is no need to mention that $f$ is not constant, Rolle works regardless. This is why I find this exercise odd: it is extremely convoluted for no reason.

Comment: @Raoul Yes, exactly what I thought. I wondered if I overlooked some detail or something because it seems like a direct consequence. Thanks for both of your comments.

Comment: Adding that unneccessary assumption helps you thinking directly about what you can say about the variations of a (non-constant) function having the same value at the boundary of some interval. Hence ... Rolle's theorem. In that regard, I do not find the statement odd at all. @Raoul

Comment: A more interesing problem: Show $\exists$ a point $x \in [0, 1]$ such that $f'(x)$ is a nonzero rational.

Comment: This might actually be the question! Or show that there is a point $x$ where $f'(x)$ is **ir**rational.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Rolle, there is $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f'(x)=0.$ Then $f'(x)$ is rational.